# Deploying gatsbyv2 with material-kit-react fail

Tags: reactjs, window, material-ui, github-pages, gatsby

my problem resides around Gatsby's production build failing to make project, which would seem and work as it should.

My goal is to adapt material-kit-react into Gatsbyv2 generated project.

[done project in develop mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AHRW.png)

so far so good i managed to do it all no problem, site looks exactly like it should in developer mode on my computer, but when i tried to put it on Github pages Gatsby build command needed to be executed, and when it did i errors appear around window object which is not defined on server where project tries to run when building (or something like that source: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/309 ). I resolved all of those errors as Gatsby employee suggested using if statement to not use window when its undefined, an it worked just fine, Gatsby ended its 'gatsby build' function and automatically published it to Github Pages thanks to ""deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public""

After deploying however something strange happens to my site
[project after publishing it onto Github pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lK1j.png)

i found that it may be because css random class generator overlap somewhere, so i added JssProvider with generateRandomClassName from @material-ui/core into new layout component and it kida worked
[material ui random name generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q792Z.png)

but effect was far from desired: 
[deployed project after adding random class generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgzWt.png)

and i tried to found whats wrong with this code, but i don't understand everything in react and gatsby yet and im empty of ideas. no errors, no eslint warning, everything falls apart anyway with no visible sign for me.

here is source material: https://github.com/Thrajnor/Gatsby-material-ui/tree/master/landingpage

and here is deployed page after build: https://thrajnor.github.io/Gatsby-material-ui/

i would really appreciate help or even a little advice in whats happening